# Rainbow Six Siege Insane Load times? Computer or Internet?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

I have a high-end computer with decent ethernet yet whenever I join a game in Siege everyone finishes loading and it takes me 1-5 minutes. Is this because of my internet or computer?

Specs:

CPU - i7-7700k
GPU - GTX 1080
16GG RAM
5900 RPM 4TB Hard drive

Comment: Do you have HD textures pack DLC installed ?

Comment: @arghtype Yes, would that slow it down?

Comment: yes! I will put an answer about it

Answer (score 3):

I think the real bottleneck here is your hard drive and/or your internet connection. Seeing your specs, [your CPU is way better than mine](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-7700K-vs-AMD-FX-8350/3647vs1489), and [so is your GPU](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1080-vs-Nvidia-GTX-960/3603vs3165). Yet, your loading time is 1-5 minutes, while I'm never above 30s.

I advise you buy an SSD and store your games on it, the loading times are amazing! A 4TB one would be pretty expensive, but do you really need this much storage? The usual compromise is system+games on SSD, music/video/pictures/etc on hdd. Moreover, if you're using steam/uplay/origin/whichever one I forgot, you can install/uninstall games without loosing progression. I really doubt you're playing 4TB of games simultaneously, so a 500/750 Go SSD should be enough, and it should greatly decrease your loading time.

Comment: Even just a 7200 rpm HDD would be better.

Comment: @TheLethalCroft I went straight from 5900rpm to ssd, so I can't really talk about 7200rpm, but thanks for the tip

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is to make sure that the drive isn't full-full. Traditional rule of thumb is to have at least 15-20% of the drive empty for HDD, and a bit more for SSDs

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was HD Texture Pack DLC which increased load times dramatically. Try uninstalling it.

Alternatively, you can try moving game textures to some kind of [RAM Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) which in theory should help with increasing speed of HDD reads.